# Reduction of differential operators

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, operators

Suppose my code outputs the expression

$$\frac{f^{(0,2)}(r,\phi )+r \left(f^{(1,0)}(r,\phi )+r f^{(2,0)}(r,\phi )\right)}{r^2}$$

This is simply the Laplacian $\nabla^2f(r, \phi)$. Is there a way for Mathematica to recognize and simplify this?

Comment: I do not know how this will work. How is Mathematica going to know that $\nabla^2(r,\phi)$ is Laplacian in polar coordinates vs. $\nabla^2(x,y)$ in cartesian coordinates? i.e. if you managed to convert it to that form, how will you use it? When you tell M now to give you the Laplacian, you have to tell it the coordinates system. if you just want this for typestting and not for code, use Latex. That is what I do.

Comment: @Nasser You can specify the coordinates for the [Laplacian](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Laplacian.html). This problem arises when my output is four lines of algebra and I'd like it to reduce to something that is more recognizable

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to write the result with an inactive `Laplacian[]`, or it will expand.

Example:

```
expr = Laplacian[r f[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"]
(*
  2*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, θ] + 
    (f[r, θ] + Derivative[0, 2][f][r, θ] + r*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, θ])/r + 
    r*Derivative[2, 0][f][r, θ]
*)
```

Transformation functions:

```
xfLaplacian[{f_, h_}, v_List, chart_] := 
  Function[e, 
    e /. First@
      Solve[Laplacian[f, v, chart] == Inactive[Laplacian][f, v, chart], 
       D[h @@ v, {First@v, 2}]]] /. 
   HoldPattern[s_Solve] :> With[{sol = s}, sol /; True];
xfLaplacian[f_, v_List, chart_] := 
  Function[e, 
    e /. First@
      Solve[Laplacian[f, v, chart] == Inactive[Laplacian][f, v, chart], 
       D[f, {First@v, 2}]]] /. 
   HoldPattern[s_Solve] :> With[{sol = s}, sol /; True];
```

Tests:

```
Simplify[expr, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, xfLaplacian[f[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"]}]
(*  f[r, θ]/r + r*Inactive[Laplacian][f[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"] +
      2*Derivative[1, 0][f][r, θ]  *)

Simplify[expr, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, xfLaplacian[{r f[r, θ], f}, {r, θ}, "Polar"]}]
(*  Inactive[Laplacian][r f[r, θ], {r, θ}, "Polar"]  *)
```

For `Solve` to work in `xfLaplacian[]`, the derivative has to be a fairly simple expression, which is why the head `f` needs to be specified in this last example.